# How to Acces Amazon Server through Public Dns

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am newbie to amazon webserver. On my windows instance i have installed apache webserver. When using localhost in browser it shows the page **"it works"** but i am unable to get this page from public DNS. ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need open the firewall:

```
1. create a security group, such as `IIS-web-group`

2. set inbound ports

Type    Protocol    Port Range    Source
HTTP    TCP         80            0.0.0.0/0

3. assign this security group to that ec2 instance.
```

Then do a telnet test from your client, such as your computer

```
telnet ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com 80
```

if you can telnet, then you should be fine to access the web site now.