# Mysql cannot connect AWS RDS on terminal

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a AWS RDS instance running on the free tier, and am trying to use `mysql` command to connect it, just to play with it.

The command I used is

```
mysql -h XXX.XXX.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u username -p
```

but after a while it returns

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XXX.XXX.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (60)

The instance I am running on AWS is MySQL, and I used the correct server address when connecting. Can anyone tell my why the connection does not get through?

Comment: This indicates your connect request is timing out -- that is, your MySQL instance at AWS doesn't see the request. Are you sure `mysqld` is running? Are you sure it's listening on the ethernet interface and not just on the loopback interface? Is there firewalling of port 3306?

Comment: @OllieJones Why is it `mysqld`? The server should be running the db instance and my computer should be the client, isn't it?

Comment: Have you configured the security group that your rds instance is in to allow inbound connections from your location?

Comment: @FrederickCheung No I didn't. I'm new to AWS so I didn't know anything about the security config you mentioned. Can you provide more info? Thanks.

Comment: In a nutshell there's a firewall that defaults to letting nothing in ( http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27676105/how-to-acces-amazon-server-through-public-dns